# sqlite passing result from a subquery as LIKE argument

Tags: sqlite

I have a query where I want to delete all the entries which belongs to a date. I am missing how to pass a LIKE argument from the sub-query. The idea is to match a date from the last entry and delete all the matched entries.

```
DELETE FROM logentries WHERE datetime(timestamp) LIKE----(SELECT  date(timestamp) FROM logentries ORDER BY datetime(timestamp) ASC LIMIT 1);
```

How to have the above 2 queries in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `LIKE` (there's no pattern matching here), use `=`:

```
DELETE FROM logentries WHERE DATE(timestamp) = (SELECT DATE(timestamp) FROM logentries ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! That did the trick. I dont know how could I miss this :(  Anyway thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

You must convert your dates to string and it will do the trick.

Comment: In Sqlite the dates are stored as string, there is no date type.